# Bluemix and Softlayer services exclusively in Canada

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is it possible to launch Bluemix exclusively on Softlayer's Canadian servers? All Bluemix and Softlayer data stored, processed, and transferred within Canada only?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not a **public** instance of Bluemix available on Canadian only servers (Bluemix comes in a public cloud, private cloud and on-premise version). Since Softlayer is the hosting platform for Bluemix and there are [two data centers in Canada](http://www.softlayer.com/data-centers) (Toronto and Montreal), it may be possible to have a private cloud instances installed there.

Another option would be an on-premise install of Bluemix on servers of your choice which could then contain Bluemix and its data on any server in the world.

Contact [Bluemix sales](http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/local/) for more info.

Comment: THANK YOU BEN! I have been calling sales for three days. Can you ask them to check their voice mail please?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Whom have you called/left messages with?

Comment: 1-844-BLUEMIX (toll free)
1-267-238-3490

Comment: I also emailed Bluemix for a call

Comment: I will follow up for you. Apologies for the lack of response!